# "python_init: Python version mismatch" logged in Apache error.log

Tags: apache-2.2, python, trac

Installed the [BitNami Trac Stack](http://bitnami.org/stack/trac) on a new Windows 2003 R2 Virtual Server to replace an aging Subversion/Trac installation on a rapidly failing physical server. I am adapting the default installation a little to make Subversion available through HTTP. I added LDAP support to Apache and restarted the service to be presented with the following messages:

```
[error] python_init: Python version mismatch, expected '2.5', found '2.5.4'.
[error] python_init: Python executable found 'D:\\PROJEC~1\\apache2\\bin\\httpd.exe'.
[error] python_init: Python path being used 'D:\\PROJEC~1\\apache2\\bin\\python25.zip;D:\\PROJEC~1\\apache2\\bin\\DLLs;D:\\PROJEC~1\\apache2\\bin\\lib;D:\\PROJEC~1\\apache2\\bin\\lib\\plat-win;D:\\PROJEC~1\\apache2\\bin\\lib\\lib-tk;D:\\PROJEC~1\\apache2\\bin'.
```

It doesn't appear to affect the performance of Apache or Trac, searching through various forums doesn't give an answer although there are quite a few posts mentioning problems adding users in Trac with the above errors.

- Is this a false error report?
- Can the message be resolved or suppressed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because the version of mod_python you're using was compiled for Python 2.5 and not 2.5.4.

On Windows that's not really a problem because the python library is loaded dynamically, so you'll always have the latest version.

It's unlike unix systems where it's static.

What you can do to remove this warning, is compiling your version of mod_python for your actual version of Python, but preferably use the [latest version of mod_python](http://httpd.apache.org/modules/python-download.cgi) (3.3.1 now).

Comment: On UNIX systems mod_python wouldn't normally link statically to Python library either so long as Python was installed such that it provided a shared library.